# How do I use a UDF with a select statement?

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I created a scalar user defined function that will accept a date of birth and return the age a person will be in 15 years from now.

```
CREATE FUNCTION AgeIn15 (@DateOfBirth DATE)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN Convert(INT, DateAdd(year, 15, DateDiff(year, @DateOfBirth, GetDate())))
END
```

Now I want to Use the UDF created to show the age of all persons in my table marketing_list along with their original information. How do I do this? I tried this but I got an error

```
SELECT *
FROM marketing_list AgeIn15(marketing_list.DateOfBirth)

SELECT *
    ,AgeIn15(marketing_list.Date_of_Birth)
FROM marketing_list
WHERE AgeIn15(Date_of_Birth) > 45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add schema name:

```
SELECT *, dbo.AgeIn15(m.Date_of_Birth) AS col_name
FROM marketing_list AS m;

SELECT *
    ,dbo.AgeIn15(m.Date_of_Birth) AS col_name
FROM marketing_list m
WHERE dbo.AgeIn15(m.Date_of_Birth) > 45
```

Optionally you can use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
Select *
from marketing_list AS m
CROSS APPLY (SELECT dbo.AgeIn15(m.Date_of_Birth)) AS c(col_name)
```

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bc355/4)**

```
SELECT  *, dbo.AgeIn15(t.c) AS col_name
FROM (SELECT '2000-01-01') AS t(c);

SELECT  *
FROM (SELECT '2000-01-01') AS t(c)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT dbo.AgeIn15(t.c)) AS c(col_name)
```

Your function should looks like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.AgeIn15 (@DateOfBirth DATE)
RETURNS INTEGER
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN DATEDIFF(year,@DateOfBirth,GETDATE()) + 15
END
```

What you did doesn't make any sense:

```
Convert(integer,DateAdd(year,15,DateDiff(year,@DateOfBirth,GetDate())))
```

1. Calculate `DATEDIFF`      - it returns number years **OK**
2. `DATEADD(year, 15, number)` - it returns date  15 years + of `1900-01-number` **FAIL**
3. `CONVERT(INTEGER, DATE)`    - it returns number of days starting at `1900-01-01`  **FAIL**

Comment: Thanks..I tried the first one but I'm getting ages starting from 5493 when the person was 15 yrs old..should be getting 30

Comment: @user2127184 Your function doesn't make sense. I rewrite it and make new demo

Comment: Hey please bare with me but this is the first I'm seeing this syntax so I don't know what the 't' and 'c' means. I see derived table and column. I want to display age along with all the information in my table marketing_list

Comment: @user2127184 t and c are just aliases, you could use any name that is valid identifier

Comment: @user2127184 See first two queries, they are yours, demo is to show how it works only

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION AgeIn15 (@DateOfBirth DATE)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 
       -- get the year today + 15 years
       (
          (DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE() ) + 15) - 
          -- minus the year of date of birth
          DATEPART(YEAR,@DateOfBirth)
       )
       -- its like saying (2015 + 15)-09-29 - (1990)-09-19 = 40
END

SELECT *
    , dbo.AgeIn15(mlist.Date_of_Birth) AS [AgeAfterFifteenYears]
FROM marketing_list AS mlist
```

hopefully this helps